# Asynchronous request about React Native

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

Now I am using React Native with Firebase to build a project. The logic is simple: I want the Error Messages will be presented on the screen after the loginUser() failed. However, due to asy problem, the error messages will not appear at the first login fail because the loginUser haven't finished, and the last time I successfully login the messages still appear because the login success state has not been changed.

```
onButtonPress() {
      const { email, password } = this.props;
      this.props.loginUser({ email, password });

      this.renderError();
  }
```

I send a loginUser Request to Firebase and then if it is successful login, the state of "error" will be empty. But it is failed, the "Error" will be a string. The related Actions and Reducers are showed below.

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
  };
};
```

inside reducer:

```
case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state, user: action.payload, error: '', loading: false, password: ''
      };
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state, error: 'Authentication Failed', password: '', loading: false
      };
```

I don't know how to deal with this asy issue, how can I make sure the renderError() function will present only after the LoginUser finished?

Comment: Can you add your `renderError` function?

Comment: I presume that both `loginUserSuccess()` and `loginUserFail()` are action creators that dispatch actions, that, in turn change the redux state. Instead of calling `this.renderError()` there, you might want to check for new props. Will be glad to leave an answer if you still don't get it

Comment: @Dane Hello, I handled this problem in a tricky way, it works well but i still want to learn how correctly resolve this. Could you leave your answers for me? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing an asynchronous piece of code synchronously. First, you should `return firebase.auth()` in your action. Then you can use promises `this.props.loginUser({ email, password }).then(/* .. */)`, `then()` will be executed after Firebase responds to the request. Finally, add a condition based on your state that wraps your `this.renderError()`, typically this should be in your JSX and not in your function logic.